# Could Not Load Assembly .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

whenever I build my web solution  I get this error :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'dotless.Core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96b446c9e63eae34' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

I have VS 2010 with .NET 4.0 on Windows 7.

The dlls are located inside the Bin folder of the Web Application.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: where is 'dotless.Core'?

Comment: inside the Bin folder. But when I remove it and build the same error occurs for the next dll.

Answer (score 24):

I deleted temporary asp.net files in :

C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

And it worked.

Comment: I too got this error `HRESULT: 0x80070057` when i was using the Mvc Application and the problem was in failed to load the assembly MvcContrib, the `System.IO.LoadAssembly` Error. I did the same and got the problem corrected.

Comment: This will help any one facing the issues. I deleted the contents from `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

Comment: Thanks!  We had a power outage right before this issues started, and your solution fixed it.  +1

Comment: Had the same issue, deleted the content of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` and it worked. Power outage here as well :) Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. This answer worked for me as well. Internet outage seemed to have caused it for me.

Answer (score 4):

had the same problem! I found that you need to use a different location for win7/x86/x64

Clear out the temporary framework files for your project in:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

For **Windows 7**, the path is:

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

For **64 bit** systems with 'Framework' in the path the full path is:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

[Found the solution here](http://blkarwasara.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/hresult-0x80070057-einvalidarg-on-debug.html)

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this from IIS? If so check the framework version that is selected for your site.

Comment: I am running it using VS 2010. When Rebuild all the solution I get the error. I check the solution and it is .NET 4.0