# Azure project does not run locally - can't find assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm struggling for 2 days with this. I have a solution with 4 projects inside:

- Web
- Service
- Objects
- Dal

When I set a Web project as a startup project and run it, it all works fine. 
Now I add a blank Azure Cloud Service project to a solution and manually 
add Web project as a new Web Role Project. When I run newly added Azure 
Cloud Service, cloud emulator starts, but project fails to run because
it can't find AutoMapper.dll (Web project uses it). If I add AutoMapper.dll
to GAC it moves forward to the next external assembly (in my case Dapper.dll).
I double check, and all my external assemblies has Copy Local set to true.

Why does cloud project search in a GAC and not in a bin folder? I must do something terribly wrong so please help me.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a nuget package. Can you try uninstalling and installing the package for the external DLL?

Comment: I managed to solve a problem with this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865299/could-not-load-assembly-net-4-0

Comment: @JanezGorše if you solved your issue please create an answer detailing what you did and if the SO question allowed you to do this please link to that and then mark it as the accepted answer so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with deleting temporary file in C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files.